# TypeError: object of type 'Tensor' has no len()

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, speech-recognition, attributeerror

Hi am trying to get the length of files. am using tf version 1.14.0 and keras 2.2.4. But the below code is written in 2.6 version. Am getting error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'Tensor' has no len()
```

Can anyone help to change the code for `tf==1.14.0`?

My datasets are audio files around 3000 files.

```
**filenames = tf.io.gfile.glob(str(data_dir) + '/*/*')
filenames = tf.random.shuffle(filenames)
num_samples = len(filenames)
print('Number of total examples:', num_samples)
print('Number of examples per label:',
      len(tf.io.gfile.listdir(str(data_dir/commands[0]))))
print('Example file tensor:', filenames[0])**
```

Comment: You have used `len()` twice in the code. Can you tell where the error is coming from? It would be better if you can provide full error traceback.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, am trying to run the code from this link https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio tensorflow version-1.14.0 and  keras 2.2.4

Comment: when I print no-of samples it should return "3000" but right now getting error because I changed the tf and keras version into 1.14.0 and 2.2.4 respectively.

Comment: @shivashankari instead of `len(filenames)` use `filenames.shape[0]`  or `tf.shape(filenames)[0]` and for the second len as well.

Answer (score 1):

`len()` might not be supported for a Tensor for Tensorflow version 1.14.0. Use `.shape` instead.

`num_samples = filenames.shape[0]`.

Comment: In the same program am getting error "AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'to_sparse'" When i run the below code.**AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_files)
waveform_ds = files_ds.map(get_waveform_and_label, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)**

Comment: @shivashankari you will get multiple errors when trying to run code meant for one Tensorflow version in another Tensorflow version because each version makes a lot of breaking changes, sometimes entire modules and features are removed or updated. I suggest you run the code in the Tensorflow version that it was designed for to avoid further errors.